# Find identity and inverse of the operation $x*y= | x - y |$, on $\Bbb R$. Does the identity exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am confused as to how we open the abs value, do we get $e=0$ and $e=2x$, or does the identity not exist?

Thanks.

Comment: $2x$ isn't an identity element (the identity must satisfy $a*e=a$ for all $a$, it can't be a function of $a$.

Comment: Note that $x\circ y=|x-y|$ is not associative, i.e., $(x\circ y)\circ z=x\circ (y\circ z)$ need not be true. So $(\Bbb R,\circ)$ is not a group anyway. Rather $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is a metric. Is there a confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity $e$ does not exist because it should satisfy e.g. $-3=-3*e=|-3-e|\ge0.$

Comment: now it makes sense, got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if the identity $e$ did exist, then for negative $n$ we would have

$$n=n*e=|n-e|\ge 0.$$